# Semaphore not initialised properly with sem_open

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I am trying to implement the producer and consumer problem with semaphores. I think I got the logic correct but my code isn't working as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
 
int arr[BUFFER_SIZE];
int position;
 
sem_t *mutex, *empty, *filled;
 
void* producer(void* args){
    printf("Prod starting\n");
    int a,b;
    sem_getvalue(empty, &a);
    sem_getvalue(mutex, &b);

    printf("empty : %d mutex : %d\n", a, b);

    do{
        sem_wait(empty);
        sem_wait(mutex);
         

        int new = rand()%2000;
        printf("Adding %d to buffer\n", new);
        arr[position] = new;
        position++;

        sem_post(mutex);
        sem_post(filled);
    }while(1);
 
}
 
void* consumer(void* arg){printf("Consumer starting\n");
    do{
        sem_wait(filled);
        sem_wait(mutex);
         
        position--;
        printf("Consuming %d from buffer", arr[position]);
        arr[position] = 0; 

        sem_post(mutex);
        sem_post(empty);
    }while(1);
}
 
 
int main() 
{ 
    mutex = sem_open("mutex", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
    empty = sem_open("empty", O_CREAT, 0644, BUFFER_SIZE);
    filled = sem_open("filled", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
    pthread_t prod, cons;

    int a, b,c;
    sem_getvalue(empty, &a);
    sem_getvalue(filled, &b);
    sem_getvalue(mutex, &c);
    printf("empty:%d filled:%d mutex:%d\n", a,b,c);

    //printf("Producer = %ld  Consumer = %ld\n", prod, cons);
     
    pthread_create(&prod,NULL,producer,NULL); 
    pthread_create(&cons,NULL,consumer,NULL); 
     
    pthread_join(prod,NULL); 
    pthread_join(cons,NULL); 
     
    sem_close(mutex);
    sem_unlink("mutex");
    sem_close(empty);
    sem_unlink("empty");
    sem_close(filled);
    sem_unlink("filled");
    return 0; 
}
```

The semaphores are not getting initialised properly, known from the following output:

```
empty:0 filled:0 mutex:0
Prod starting
empty : 0 mutex : 0
Consumer starting
```

I don't understand why the semaphores are not initialising properly. From the man pages:

> sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode, unsigned int value);

> If O_CREAT is specified in oflag, then two additional arguments
> must be supplied.  The mode argument specifies the permissions to
> be placed on the new semaphore, the value
> argument specifies the initial value for the new semaphore.

Note: I can't use sem_init as the final code needs to be done on Macos. I am simply recreating this on linux with sem_getvalue() to know the problem.

At @pilcrow's suggestion, I recreated the problem to this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 

sem_t *mutex;

void* thread(void* arg){
    printf("Entered thread\n");
    sem_wait(mutex);
    printf("Hello\n");
    sem_post(mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() 
{ 
    mutex = sem_open("mutex", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);

    if(mutex == SEM_FAILED){
        printf("Failed to create semaphore\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    pthread_t id;
    pthread_create(&id,NULL,thread,NULL); 
    pthread_join(id,NULL); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
Entered thread
```

The thread keeps waiting indefinitely for the *mutex* semaphore which was not, again, initialised properly.

Comment: Always check the return value of everything.

Comment: sem_open() is working fine. I checked by comparing return value with SEM_FAILED and it seems to work with no errors from sem_open.

Comment: Try specifying O_EXCL.

Comment: Can you pare this down to a concise [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Since you are having trouble with the initialization of newly opened semaphores, could you cut out two of the semaphores, the producer, and the consumer?

Comment: @pilcrow As you said, I made a similar scenario and it still doesn't work. I updated the question.

Comment: @Ku-hello, thank you and +1.  I would (a) add O_EXCL as n.m. suggested (and you'll need to unlink in `main` perhaps right before you `open`), (b) print out `errno` if it fails, and, separately (c) change the name of the mutex to be POSIX compliant:  `/mutex` (with the leading slash).  That's all I can think of offhand

Comment: Your second example works fine for me (once I added `<fcntl.h>`). If the problem is really the semaphore value, an extra `sem_post` just before `pthread_join` should unblock your thread, right? Have you tried, to confirm the hypothesis?

Comment: Oh, your semaphore is persisting across runs, right? Try adding `sem_unlink` at the start of your test to make sure you're not inheriting an old value.

Comment: @Useless Using `<fcntl.h>` didn't do anything. Adding `sem_post` before `pthread_join` did work as it should but this solution can't be generalised well and the issue seems to be with `sem_open`. More, importantly, what do you mean persisting across runs? After I tried putting extra `sem_post`(when the code worked), I ran again removing it and now it works!! Why and how?

Comment: @pilcrow Surely I will for (b). Regarding (a), It seems the semaphores "persists" as pointed out by @Useless, so using unlink before open somehow "refreshes" the semaphore? I would be thankful if one of you answers on this persisting behaviour of semaphores. For (c), sorry that I don't also know how `/` helps. It would be helpful to know your insights on this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my local `sem_overview` manpage, yours may differ:

> A  named  semaphore  is  identified  by  a name of the form `/somename`; that is, a null-terminated string of up to `NAME_MAX-4`
> (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are  slashes.   Two
> processes can operate on the same named semaphore by passing the same name to `sem_open(3)`.

> The `sem_open(3)`  function creates a new named semaphore or opens an existing named semaphore.  After the semaphore has been
> opened, it can be operated on using `sem_post(3)` and `sem_wait(3)`.  When a process has finished using the  semaphore,  it  can
> use  `sem_close(3)`  to close the semaphore.  When all processes have finished using the semaphore, it can be removed from the
> system using `sem_unlink(3)`.

The fact that multiple processes can open the same semaphore, means it must exist somewhere outside the scope of a process.

The fact that it requires manual unlinking, suggests it continues existing even when every process which opened it has called `sem_close()` (otherwise it could just be destroyed when the ref count became zero).

Running your test process under `strace` on linux shows that the semaphore is backed by a file `/dev/shm/sem/mutex`. Other platforms may have different backing locations, but must support the same semantics.

The obvious corollary of needing to manually unlink the semaphore, is that if you *don't*, you get the same semaphore every time you open it with the same name. The value passed to `sem_open` isn't used *unless* the semaphore is created. If the semaphore with that name already existed (because it hasn't been unlinked), it just contains whatever value was left over from the previous run or runs.

If you really only want to use semaphores inside a single process and cannot use an unnamed one (with `sem_init()`), you should probably make sure the name is unique. Forming a string from the PID would be a good start, as would unlinking it on exit.

Comment: That explains my original problem too. When I ran the code first time, the producer-consumer problem worked fine. After I did some clean ups and ran it again to confirm, it started to fail again and again. Thanks a lot dude. Good suggestion at the end too ;)

Comment: Also, there is too less material on this behaviour of named semaphores, I never saw this until now.